# Proving that Hopf link is fibered

Tags: geometry, geometric-topology, knot-theory

What’s the simplest way to show that  the Hopf link is a fibered knot with the Hopf band as fiber surface and that its monodromy is a Dehn twist along the core of the Hopf band?

Comment: I think i found what i was looking for in the article “Fibred links in S3” written by S. Baader, C. Graf.

Comment: I would suggest writing up your own answer in that case.  And perhaps adding some details would be helpful for others with similar questions.